# How can I specify a path pattern of "/" in a CloudFront behavior?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution with an S3 origin. I want to create a behavior such that requests to the root path of the site will use a different origin (a webservice).

So ideally my behaviors would be:

- "/" - webservice origin
- Default (*) - S3 bucket

However, the above doesn't seem to work - the root request isn't caught by the first behavior.

Is there any way I can accomplish what I want using path patterns?

Comment: I would expect `/` to do it, but I'll test.  When testing, you did verify that you weren't seeing a cached response, I take it?  Assuming it doesn't work (though it seems like it *should*), then you might be able to do the opposite, making the default `*` behavior go to the site server, then using `/?*` to send everything else to the bucket, since that should capture everything with one or more characters after `/`.

Comment: No - there's no page in the root of the bucket so I just get the error page I've defined in the S3 bucket (so presumably this response wouldn't be cached). I should have mentioned - I had tried the approach of inverting the conditions and having the default behavior go to the webservice, but that doesn't work either. Even if I specify the pattern for the first behavior as something like "/???*" then root requests are still caught by that one, and don't fall through to the default * behavior.

Comment: CloudFront [does cache errors](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HTTPStatusCodes.html).  Check the response headers for an `Age:` header.  If present, that's how long ago (in seconds) CloudFront cached the response you're looking at.

Comment: I've can't duplicate the behavior you report.  I've confirmed that the path pattern `/` matches the root only, sending it to one origin, while the `*` on the default behavior sends everything else to the other origin.  But... did you set a [default root object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html) for the distribution?  If so, that's evaluated *before* the path pattern is matched, and that would explain the behavior.  That option doesn't do what many people assume.

Comment: Yes that was it - the default root object. If you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this for any folder? So I want anything that would translate to an `index.html` call to go to a different origin (a web server). Things like `/`, `test`, `test/` would all go to my web app origin, and everything else to S3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is that a Cache Behavior with a Path Pattern of '/' does work to only match the root url. In this particular case, the user also had a default root object set which gets matched before the behavior patterns. Removing the default root object is necessary if you wish to define a cache behavior on the root url using the '/' pattern.

Comment: That's really helpful, I wasted 2 hours looking for a reason that was appending the /index.html to my paths

Answer (score 0):

In addition to clearing my default root object like the other answer says, I had to set a different cache policy for my two behaviors. This was because CloudFront was using default cache key for the object.

I first added a custom header to my origin configurations
[image]

And then I made a new cache policy which referenced this custom header in the cache key.

[image]